# How can I make this formal paragraph more exciting, engaging and friendly?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, proofreading

Text: 
"Your order has been received. A digital proof of your personalized item will be sent to you via Etsy Conversation within 1 business day of placing your order. With your confirmation that the personalized item has been created to your liking, a high-resolution PDF and JPEG will be sent to you via Etsy Conversation. Simply print your item at home or your local print shop! We hope you absolutely love your customized order!"

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the members of the forum to do the work that you should be doing. This forum is dedicated to helping you learn to be a better writer. If you had provided some alternative language and asked a specific question about it (for example, which option gives a better result in exciting the reader), we might be able to answer it. But I did not see anything resembling such as question.

Here is what I would like to see in a question:

- This is what I am trying to accomplish (theme, intent)
- This is what I have tried (hopefully more than one thing)
- This is the problem or deficiency as I see it (more than "it is
  wrong")
- This is the criteria that I will use to judge the answer (more
  objective than subjective)

Please edit your question to provide the information that we need to answer it.

Comment: This is more of an extended comment than an answer, but you're absolutely right; this question isn't suitable in its current form.

Comment: @SHE Unfortunately, that's not correct. This site *is* about writing, but questions asking for writing critiques, or help re-writing paragraphs, are explicitly off-topic here. I'd recommend taking the [tour] and visiting the [help] to learn more about the kinds of questions you *can* ask, and why the site works like this.

Comment: The comment field was not large enough for what I had to say.